# How can I get the localised Unit Symbol from a MeasurementFormatter result?

Tags: ios, swift, measurementformatter

I'm trying to get the localised unit symbol for any measurement obtained using a measurement formatter.

For example, if the locale uses degrees Fahrenheit, but the app stores it's data in Celsius, I would create a measurement formatter as follows:

```
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
let measurement = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
formatter.string(from: measurement)
```

This last line will give me "50°F".
Now I want to get the "°F" value from the measurement.

I have tried using

```
formatter.string(from: measurement.unit)
```

But this just gives me "deg. C"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Could you share it?

Answer (score 2):

You probably just have to set the locale of the formatter like this:

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
```

Or if you want to get the current locale of the device and set it from that do like this:

```
formatter.locale = Locale.current
```

and then

```
formatter.string(from: measurement.unit)
```

Comment: this **does not work** since it returns the localized provided unit, which is Celsius and not Farenheit. Note that even in en-US, localized celsius is celsius... the unit will not change unless it is converted first.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, building on Lars answer and Daniel's comment, the following code allows you to get a localized unit and value:

```
let measurement = Measurement<UnitTemperature>(value: 10, unit: .celsius)
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()

let localMeasurement = measurement.converted(to: UnitSpeed(forLocale: .autoupdatingCurrent))

let unit = formatter.string(from: localMeasurement.unit)
let value = localMeasurement.value //.rounded()
```

Answer (score -1):

With my Mac pref set to en_US with the temperature in Fahrenheit, the following code gives me what you want in Objective-C:

```
NSUnitTemperature * fahrenheit = [NSUnitTemperature fahrenheit];
NSMeasurement * measurement = [[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:35 unit:fahrenheit];
NSMeasurementFormatter * formatter = [[NSMeasurementFormatter alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%@", measurement.unit.symbol); // °F
```

This output: °F

Answer (score -4):

In order to get the "°F", I think that you must set the locale of the formatter to "en_US".